# VBA Randomize values from 1 to 30 thereby skipping manually entered values

Tags: excel, vba, loops, random

For the first 15 ranks, I want to manually enter the values in B2:P11. For ranks 16 to 30, I want to randomize these values using an Excel VBA button, with the following code:

```
Sub rand_group()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim myFlag(1 To num_man)
    Dim s_group As Worksheet
    Set s_group = Worksheets("group")


    'óêêîånóÒÇèâä˙âª
    Randomize
    
    s_group.Cells.Clear
    s_group.Range("A1") = "group_id"
    
    For i = 1 To num_group
      s_group.Cells(i + 1, 1) = i
    Next i
    For i = 1 To num_man
      s_group.Cells(1, i + 1) = "m_rank" & i
    Next i
    
    For i = 1 To num_group
      For j = 16 To num_man
        myFlag(j) = False
      Next j
      For j = 16 To num_man
        Do
          'óêêî=Int((ç≈ëÂíl - ç≈è¨íl +1 ) * Rnd + ç≈è¨íl)
          myNum = Int((num_man - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1)
        Loop Until myFlag(myNum) = False
        
        s_group.Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Value = myNum
        myFlag(myNum) = True
      Next j
    Next i

End Sub
```

However, **these random values should neglect the manually entered values in B2:P11**

How can I change the code to fix this?

Screenshot of the excel file is displayed below:
[I want to manually fill values from B2 to P11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QSg7.png)

Thank you in advance for your response!

Michiel

Comment: Remove `s_group.Cells.Clear`

Comment: Would you mind elaborating a little on what code to include? Thank you in advance!

Comment: This indeed prevents the manually entered code to be deleted. However, when randomizing Q2:AE11, the values in B2:P11 are still included. Would you mind elaborating a little on what code to include? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fill in the random section of the grid, the `myFlag` array is not needed. Just use the cell coordinates to set the random values. Also remove the `Clear` call since that clears the entire sheet.

To prevent duplicate numbers in a row, use the excel `CountIf` function in a loop until a unique random number is found.

Here is the updated code. It can be run multiple times without affecting the manual data.

```
Sub DoRand()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim s_group As Worksheet
    Set s_group = Worksheets("group")
    
    num_group = 10
    num_man = 30
    
    Randomize
    
    's_group.Cells.Clear  ' clear sheet
    
    ' build table
    For i = 1 To num_group  ' group id
      s_group.Cells(i + 1, 1) = i
    Next i
    For i = 1 To num_man  ' column names
      s_group.Cells(1, i + 1) = "m_rank" & i
    Next i
    
    ' fill in random numbers
    For i = 1 To num_group  'row
      For j = 16 To num_man  'column
         Do While True
            n = Int((num_man) * Rnd + 1)  ' get random number
            cnt = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(s_group.Cells(i + 1, 2), s_group.Cells(i + 1, j)), "=" & n) ' check if number in row
            s_group.Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Value = n ' set cell value
            If cnt = 0 Then Exit Do ' if unique in row, go to next cell
        Loop  ' not unique, try new random value
      Next
    Next
            
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Still, values that I manually added in range B2:P11 can appear in the random part, which crashes the entire algorithm. It is essential that no double values appear in the rows. Do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: My mistake. I did not realize that requirement. I updated the answer to ensure unique numbers per row.